# How to Change the legend's colour range when rasterizing a Spatial Object

Tags: r, spatial

my question is very simple, I am trying to create a trajectory frequencies counting from a SpatialLines Object. I can rasterize it without problems, however, I'd like to know if it is possible to change the legend's colour range from the plot result (See the image below). Thanks.[image]

Comment: Could you show your code to achieve this plot?

Comment: [this](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/text) may be useful.

Comment: Thanks. I got it with the "col" argument of the plot function. I just created a vector with the colours that I wanted and passed it to "col" like: _italic_col=colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "blue", "lightblue", "green", "yellow", "red", "darkred"))( 20 ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(raster)
x <- raster(nc=10, nr=10)
x[] <- runif(ncell(x), 0, 30)
plot(x)
```

[image: default plot]

```
#plot(x, col = rainbow(6))
brks <- c(0, 10, 20, 30)
args <- list(at=c(5, 15, 25), labels=c("Low","Med.","High"))
plot(x, col=terrain.colors(3), breaks=brks, axis.args=args)
```

[image: raster plot]